# where to find required version of rsconnect for deploying shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm trying to deploy/publish my first shiny app using RStudio. I used this code to install rsconnect:

```
install.packages('rsconnect')

library(rsconnect)
```

When i click to 'publish application' it tells me rsconnect 0.8.5 is required but 0.7 is available. I've tried going online to download the required version manually but none of the packages i've downloaded work.

Does anyone know where to get the version it's asking for?

Answer (score 0):

I've now fixed this problem. I was running an old version of RStudio which doesn't download the latest rsconnect package.